# How to install packages to external drive (and run them)?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, external-hdd

I am running Xenial 16.04 and looking to install packages to an external drive - my computer has a 32gb SSD so it would be very useful to me to be able to use an external drive.

In a quick search I found a framework called [AppImageKit](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/Creating-AppImages) which seems to be designed to package all dependencies for a program (chromium, GIMP, some python packages, etc), but haven't had time to look into it.

[This user](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/everytime-i-try-linux-i-dont-last-a-day.2377150/) seems to be looking for the same solution I am.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to install Ubuntu on the external SSD.

The "problem" is that Linux does not install programs into a single directory, so, when you install an application it installs pieces in various locations on the hard drive.

See http://brajeshwar.com/2008/filesystem-file-organization-in-linux/

So, generally what you "normally" would do is, as a part of the installation, partition the ssd and mount the various partitions at various locations such as /home or /usr or /var

So you could reinstall or move part of the file system, such as /usr to your ssd. Moving will take longer and be more involved then simply re-installing, making a partition or partitions such as /var and /usr on the ssd. The installer will do this for you.

To move see [How can I store /var on a separate partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39536/how-can-i-store-var-on-a-separate-partition)

Other options : [How to use second HDD as program installation drive path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747652/how-to-use-second-hdd-as-program-installation-drive-path)

Your last option would be to compile from source. When compiling you specify the location, again you would make a partition on the ssd and mount it at /usr/local. When compiling you use the --prefix option

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902698/linux-configure-make-prefix

So, if you did not understand what any of that means, you are best off installing Ubuntu onto the ssd.

Comment: Thank you - I'll give it a try. I have only tried symlinking folders within /etc/ or within /usr/lib and ran into some issues with that.

compiling from source would be inconvenient but an option I'll consider if everything else fails. I have been running Linux on an external USB and used to run it on an SD but would prefer the internal SSD as it is much faster.

Comment: Well it is better to mount --bind these things rather then symlink. I think the easiest would be to look at your file system and decide what partitions you want on the external. Perhaps /home ?

Comment: i was hoping to move directories such as /var /etc /lib and /usr , where packages are usually installed. the /home dir actually has files installed in both Chrome OS and Ubuntu and it could create issues moving the whole dir to another device

Comment: there are 3gb of available space on the SSD after completing an install and adding chromium-browser, filezilla, and a few other small packages (g++, gparted, python-pip3)... would be cool if i could use external storage for more packages like anaconda that are very large

Comment: You might be able to do what you want using LVM.