# When I download apps using Ubuntu can I ensure they are downloaded to an attached SSD rather than the laptops smaller HDDAND

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, snap

I have cleared Windows off my laptop and installed the latest Ubuntu on the HDD. Now I have started to download apps to run on Ubuntu can I save the downloads in their entirety to an attached SSD has much more capacity and speed than the rather ancient internal HDD?

Comment: Why do you use the `snap`-tag?

Comment: See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go. Departing from the Standard places one at risk of becoming broken and unsupportable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use second HDD as program installation drive path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747652/how-to-use-second-hdd-as-program-installation-drive-path)